# Ansible using regular expression to find GCP snapshots

Tags: ansible

I need to write a ansible playbook to search for disk snapshots in GCP.

The snapshots that I need to pick up are named like:

```
aaa-bbb-ccc-data-2020-11-30-20-58-35-sb-20201205150005
aaa-bbb-ccc-data-sb-20201204150027
```

some have time stamps in the middle(between `data` and `sb`), some do not have the time stamp in the middle. But all have the the time stamp of when the snapshot was created at the end, and it is formated like `yyyymmddhhmmss`.

Here is my code:

```
      - set_fact:
          snapshot_name: "aaa-bbb-ccc-data[-0-9]*-[s][b][-0-9]*"

      - debug: msg="{{ snapshot_name }}"

      - name: get snap
        gcp_compute_snapshot_info:
          filters:
            - name = "{{ snapshot_name }}"
          project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
          auth_kind: "{{ gcp_kind }}"
          service_account_file: "{{ gcp_file }}"
        register: snaps
      
      - debug: msg="{{ snaps }}"
```

I was hoping to get all the snapshots matching the the pattern defined in `snapshot_name`, but the result is empty:

```
TASK [get snap] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 05 June 2022  00:51:28 +0000 (0:00:00.028)       0:00:03.502 *********** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************Sunday 05 June 2022  00:51:29 +0000 (0:00:00.598)       0:00:04.100 *********** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "resources": []
    }
}
```

1. How can I set the correct pattern for `snapshot_name` so the code will pick up the snapshots I want?
2. How can I get the snapshots that I retrieved and then only pick up the latest(by the time stamp at the end of the snapshot name)?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with google cloud, but looking at [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) I think you need `~` rather than `=` if you expect to perform regex pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks @larsks. Unfortunately I can not use ```~``` since the ansible module ```gcp_compute_snapshot_info``` only takes ```=``` for snapshot name pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. I've looked at [the source](https://github.com/ansible-collections/google.cloud/blob/master/plugins/modules/gcp_compute_snapshot_info.py#L274) and I think it just uses the filters verbatim, but I don't have any way to test that.

Comment: I tried to replace ```=``` with ```r``` and the code failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I sort of solved this problem by removing the `sb` in the string, so I used:

```
      - set_fact:
          snapshot_name: "aaa-bbb-ccc-data*"

      - debug: msg="{{ snapshot_name }}"

      - name: get snap
        gcp_compute_snapshot_info:
          filters:
            - name = "{{ snapshot_name }}"
          project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
          auth_kind: "{{ gcp_kind }}"
          service_account_file: "{{ gcp_file }}"
        register: snaps
      
      - debug: msg="{{ snaps }}"
```

and the results come out correct!